# An app used SMS functionality, how to publish the app to disallow ipod touch user download

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sms, ipod-touch

I used some code like below:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sms://123"]];
```

1. what would happen if it runs in ipod touch
2. how to target iphone user only when publish the app to the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app's `Info.plist` file, set the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` property to contain `sms` as one of the keys. The App Store will handle whether or not to present your app to which devices that users browse the App Store with, and iTunes will know which devices it can sync your app to and which it can't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your applications info.plist file. It lets you restrict the application to certain devices, OS:es etc.

Look at the [UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) property which allows you to even specify that the device requires SMS :)